# Ticker Tackor Soldier Spy

Tags: java, beginner, game, tic-tac-toe, javafx

This is a Tic Tac Toe game with a "new game" button. I'm after a general review of the code with some tips on how to make it simpler and tidier.

[GitHub](https://github.com/Olleorm/TickTackToe)

HoboChess.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


public class HoboChess implements Initializable {

    @FXML Label systemOut;
    @FXML GridPane gridPane;
    final static int ROWS = 3;
    final static int COLUMNS = 3;
    int[][] grid;
    boolean turn;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        grid = new int[COLUMNS][ROWS];
        newVisualField(ROWS, COLUMNS);
    }

    public void newGame(ActionEvent action) {
        grid = new int[COLUMNS][ROWS];
        newVisualField(ROWS, COLUMNS);
    }

    public void WhoWon(int x, int[] zone){
        if (zone[x] == 3){
            systemOut.setText("Os won!");
        }else if (zone[x] == 30){
            systemOut.setText("Xs won!");
        }
    }

    public void winCheck(){
        int[] zone = new int[COLUMNS * ROWS];
        int zoneNumber = 0;

        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
                zone[zoneNumber] = grid[y][x];
                zoneNumber++;
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            if (zone[x * 3] == zone[x * 3 + 1] && zone[x * 3] == zone[x * 3 + 2]){
                WhoWon(x * 3, zone);
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            if (zone[x] == zone[x + 3] && zone[x] == zone[x + 6]){
                WhoWon(x, zone);
            }
        }
        if (zone[0] == zone[4] && zone[0] == zone[8]){
            WhoWon(0, zone);
        }else if (zone[2] == zone[4] && zone[2] == zone[6]){
            WhoWon(2, zone);
        }
    }

    public void newVisualField(int rows, int columns){
        gridPane.getChildren().clear();
        for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
                ButtonCell button = new ButtonCell(grid[x][y], x, y, this);
                gridPane.add(button.aButton, x, y);
            }
        }
    }
}

class ButtonCell {

    public Button aButton;
    boolean buttonPushed;

    ButtonCell(final int button, final int x, final int y, final HoboChess hoboChess) {
        aButton = new Button(String.valueOf(button));
        aButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                if (buttonPushed == false) {
                    if (hoboChess.turn) {
                        hoboChess.grid[y][x] = 3;
                        aButton.setText("O");
                    } else {
                        hoboChess.grid[y][x] = 30;
                        aButton.setText("X");
                    }
                    hoboChess.turn = !hoboChess.turn;
                    buttonPushed = !buttonPushed;
                    hoboChess.winCheck();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `HoboChess`?

Comment: it's the swedish name of the game ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All your fields can be declared `private`. There is really no need to expose these more than necessary.

```
@FXML private Label systemOut;
@FXML private GridPane gridPane;
private final static int ROWS = 3;
private final static int COLUMNS = 3;
private int[][] grid;
private boolean turn;
```

---

Your `initialize` and `newGame` methods looks very much the same to me, you could change your `initialize` to:

```
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    newGame(null);
}
```

---

```
public void WhoWon(int x, int[] zone){
    if (zone[x] == 3){
        systemOut.setText("Os won!");
    }else if (zone[x] == 30){
        systemOut.setText("Xs won!");
    }
}
```

@barq is correct that the method name can be improved, and that passing a single `int value` to this method should be enough, which can make it:

```
public void declareWinner(int value) {
    if (value == 3) {
        systemOut.setText("Os won!");
    } else if (value == 30) {
        systemOut.setText("Xs won!");
    }
}
```

However, these magic numbers `3` and `30` really needs to be fixed. I'd recommend an [`enum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html):

```
public enum Player {
    X, O;
}
```

And then use a `Player[][]` instead of `int[][]`. and a `Player turn` instead of `boolean`.

---

Your win-check approach is a bit... more complicated than necessary. You begin with:

```
for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        zone[zoneNumber] = grid[y][x];
        zoneNumber++;
    }
}
```

But in reality, there is no need to transform all the positions to a number, instead you can access the 2d array directly, like this:

```
for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
    if (zone[0][y] == zone[1][y] && zone[0][y] == zone[2][y]) {
        declareWinner(zone[0][y]);
    }
}
for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    if (zone[x][0] == zone[x][1] && zone[x][0] == zone[x][2]) {
        declareWinner(zone[x][0]);
    }
}
if (zone[0][0] == zone[1][1] && zone[0][0] == zone[2][2]) {
    declareWinner(zone[0][0]);
} else if (zone[2][0] == zone[1][1] && zone[2][0] == zone[0][2]) {
    declareWinner(zone[2][0]);
}
```

---

In `ButtonCell` you are doing:

```
hoboChess.grid[y][x] = 3;
```

And violà, you have flipped x and y! In other places you are doing `grid[x][y]` but here we have `grid[y][x]`. Thanks to how Tic Tac Toe works, you won't see a difference, but it is still quite important to be consistent.

Also, when changing to using an enum this can become

```
hoboChess.grid[x][y] = Player.X;
```

or

```
hoboChess.grid[x][y] = Player.O;
```

---

Overall it does look like you have improved over time. A little additional improvement I would recommend is to separate the game board and logic more from your Java FX controller class.

I would use one file for `TicTacToeGame`, containing the `Player[][]` array and who's turn it is, then I would use a method `Player makeMove(int x, int y)` that would place a mark at the specified position and return which player made the move (for the button to know what mark to set). This game logic class can be made entirely independent of your JavaFX controller, so that it can be easily used in a Java console application, a Swing application, or another framework. This is an important step and skill in programming, to be able to create re-usable classes.

Answer (score 2):

Style:

Use lowercase names for methods such as `WhoWon` by convention. When calling WhoWon(...) it looks as if you were calling a constructor of a class.

Also, the name for the method `WhoWon` could be improved to something like `determineWinner`. Method names usually start with a verb in Java by convention. You can also simplify the method by only passing the element of the array you actually need. As you are only accessing `zone[x]` passing `zone[]` and `x` separately is redundant. Simply pass `zone[x]`.